# Calculating left offset position of d3 line

Tags: jquery, d3.js, offset

I'm trying to calculate the offset of a d3 line so that I can draw a connection from that line to an image with the same class or attribute. I then pass this value to a function called draw connection lines. For example draw line, class Joe to a photo of Joe. jQuery does not recognize d3 elements to calculate their position or offset.

For example, this returns null:

var imageLeft = d3.selectAll('g.last-'+lastname).offset().left;

So if I'm trying to select a particular line, based on a class name on hover -- how can I calculate the offset. I've tried different combinations here, to no avail:

```
  var imageLeft = d3.selectAll('g.last-'+lastname).classed('highlighted',true).node().getBoundingClientRect();
  var imageLeft = document.getElementsById('g').offsetLeft;
  var imageLeft =  $(this).attr('id',lastname).offset().left;

  var imageLeft = $(this).position().left ;
  var imageLeft = d3.select(this).select('g.last-'+lastname).offset().left;
                 var imageLeft = $(this).find('.div-line').position().left ;
```

Here is the function that I need this value for (drawing the lines):

```
  function drawConnectLines(imageLeft,index) {
    d3.selectAll('line.horizontal-line')
        .attr('x1',imageLeft+$('.portrait img').width()/2)
        .attr('x2',Settings.person_interval*index+Settings.chartLeft);

    d3.selectAll('line.vertical-line.first')
        .attr('x1',imageLeft+$('.portrait img').width()/2)
        .attr('x2',imageLeft+$('.portrait img').width()/2);
    d3.selectAll('line.vertical-line.second')
        .attr('x1',Settings.person_interval*index+Settings.chartLeft)
        .attr('x2',Settings.person_interval*index+Settings.chartLeft);
}
```

Any help is appreciated -- fiddle here: http://tinyurl.com/m6eqwf3

Original lines to get left offset of are being drawn like this:

```
Plot.experience.enter().append('g')
  attr('class',function(d) 
 {return d.First+ ' last-' +d.Last;}) 
 .attr('transform',function(d,i) {return 'translate('+  (Settings.person_interval*i+Settings.chartLeft)+',0)';}) 
 .attr('x1',0) 
 .attr('x2',0) 
 .attr('y1',Settings.chartTop) 
 .attr('y2',options.height);
```

Comment: getBBox() or getBoundingClientRect() might give you what you need.

Comment: Could you use D3 for everything? It looks like you're using JQuery only to get the coordinates, which you could do with D3 as well.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff how would you use d3 to get the coordinates?

Comment: How are you setting the coordinates in the first place?

Comment: The coordinates of the line are being set in the transform for when I'm drawing the lines: Plot.experience.enter().append('g').attr('class',function(d) {return d.First+ ' last-' +d.Last;})
            .attr('transform',function(d,i) {return 'translate('+(Settings.person_interval*i+Settings.chartLeft)+',0)';})
            .attr('x1',0)
            .attr('x2',0)
            .attr('y1',Settings.chartTop)
            .attr('y2',options.height);

Comment: getBBox() or getBoundingClientRect()  do not work